# How to make datasheet view 100% of browser height

Tags: wss-3.0, datasheet

Does anyone know the best way to remove scolling or even just expand the height of the datasheet view. I have two Sharepoint WSS 3.0 site collections, one displays the default datasheet view at 100% height where my other shows it at a fixed height of about 250px I'm trying to find out where this height is set hoping I can set the height manually.

Breaking down the code I see the datasheet is in an object with an ID and name of STSListControlWPQ1 I tried to apply style to this with no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I would try IE's Developer tools (hit F12) to see which style settings are used by the views and compare the 2 pages. The dev tools will show you all styles used and whether they are for isntance inherited from a parent element and where they style rule was defined (css file, inline).

The datasheet view itself is an ActiveX control by the way, so my guess is that any "styling" related to it is actually a result of style rules applied to one of the control's parent elements.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will be better to put the datasheet view into a popup and it expand it their?

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to keep it consistent since the view does look correct in my other WSS sites. I'm just not sure where this code is being generated from and why this site collection feels the need to show a compact datasheet view. Users are finding it frustrating to only see 5 items at a time.